# What is the literal difference between "$event.target" and "$el" in Alpine.js?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

We know both the below codes show the same result, but what are their differences? Can someone explain it? Thank you.

```
<button @click="$event.target.innerHTML = 'Hello World!'">Replace me with "Hello World!"</button>
```

```
<button @click="$el.innerHTML = 'Hello World!'">Replace me with "Hello World!"</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your examples it's the same thing, *$el* result as a shortcut for *$event.target*, but you can use *$el* also outside of an event, for example I have a blade component like this:

```blade
@props(['relOption' => ''])

<div data-rel-option="{{ $relOption }}" x-show="_value==$el.dataset.relOption">
   .....
</div>
```

where *data-rel-option* is set by the backend but is used by Alpine via *$el*

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

1. [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

> a reference to the object onto which the event was dispatched

i.e. it will return the element that triggered the action, in this case it is the button that you clicked.

2. [`$el`](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/el)

> $el is a magic property that can be used to retrieve the current DOM node.

i.e. it will also select the element that triggered the action.

---

They do appear to do the same thing but Alpine provides a more concise reference to the current object.